# R: filter with string_select and two variables - syntax?

Tags: r

I am trying to replace sql with tidyverse and can't get the syntax right. Original sql:

```
delete from df where (Site='000090000002' or Site='000051896364') and (Description = 'SOUTH BOUND' or Description = 'NORTH BOUND')
```

I've tried:

```
filter(!str_detect((Description, 'SOUTH BOUND|NORTH BOUND') & (Site, '000090000002|000051896364')))
```

- Error Unexpected ','

```
filter(!str_detect(Description, 'SOUTH BOUND|NORTH BOUND' & Site, '000090000002|000051896364'))
```

- Error: unused argument

```
filter(!str_detect(Description, 'SOUTH BOUND|NORTH BOUND')&!str_detect(Site, '000090000002|000051896364'))
```

- This one deletes all rows with any of the four conditions

I hope it is possible to use filter and str_detect with more than one variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(!(Site %in% c('000090000002', '000051896364') & Description %in% c('SOUTH BOUND', 'NORTH BOUND')))
```

Comment: as I can't upvote  just to acknowledge this works and reads concisely, thx